# How to port TCPClient and NetworkStream to Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream

Why are TCPClient and NetworkStream missing from Silverlight?
Are there any known ports of TCPClient and NetworkStream to Silverlight?
If there aren't, am I allowed to copy the source code from the .NET 4 runtime into my own library?
If not, how do I start porting those classes to Silverlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some limitations on [Networking in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645029%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), mostly related to the fact that Silverlight runs in a sandbox in the browser (e.g. cross domain policy, port restrictions, and other, which can partly be solved by using OOB applications with an relaxed security model).

However, Silverlight provides some support for [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), and there are some high-level client implementations out there, like [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx).

These are maybe a good foundation to start building your own ports, because I suppose the .NET 4 runtime license does not include the right to fork source codes, not even to port them to Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks but notice the first question. Why on earth are they missing?

Comment: I suppose that the WCF/WebService, HttpWebRequest, WebClient integration seemed to be "enough" in the first versions and low-level networking was demanded later by developers when the limitaions became more frustrating. But I guess only the Silverlight Development Team will have a 100% answer to this part of your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but it was very useful for me.
Thanks jCoder, I actually created a solution based on your linked article. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/mschwarz/archive/2008/03/07/silverlight-2-and-sockets.aspx

I made a few changes.  Most notably, there is a memory leak in that TcpClient that I resolved by Disposing of the ScoketAsyncEventArgs created in the send and receive.  There may be a better way here, but it worked so I stopped looking.  Without this, it seems that a reference is kept due to subscribing to the event.  Open for suggestions.

I have only used this with a BinaryReader & BinaryWriter, your mileage may vary with other readers.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace IBApi
{
    public class TcpClientSl
    {
      private const int Receive = 1;
      private const int Send = 0;

      private bool isConnected = false;

      private Socket socket;
      private DnsEndPoint endPoint;
      public NotifyStream socketStream;

      private static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
      private static AutoResetEvent autoSendEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
      private static AutoResetEvent autoReceiveEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

      NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public TcpClientSl(string host, int port)
        {
          logger.Trace("TcpClientSl(string {0}, int {1})", host, port);

          endPoint = new DnsEndPoint(host, port, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

          socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork 
                      /* hostEndPoint.AddressFamily */, 
                      SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
          socketStream = new NotifyStream();
          socketStream.OnRead = ReadDelegate;
          socketStream.OnWrite = WriteDelegate;
        }

        int ReadDelegate (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
          //logger.Trace("ReadDelegate (byte[] buffer, int {0}, int {1})", offset, count);
            // Prepare receiving.
            SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnReceive);
            socket.ReceiveAsync(args);
            if (!autoReceiveEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)))
            {
              logger.Error("Receive Timeout");
              //this.Disconnect();
            }
            args.Dispose();
            return args.BytesTransferred;
        }

        void WriteDelegate(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
          //logger.Trace("WriteDelegate(byte[] buffer, int {0}, int {1})", offset, count);
          if (isConnected && socket.Connected)
          {
              SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
              args.SetBuffer(buffer, offset, count);
              args.UserToken = socket;
              args.RemoteEndPoint = endPoint;
              args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnSend);

              socket.SendAsync(args);

              if (!autoSendEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)))
              {
                logger.Error("Send Timeout");
                //this.Disconnect();
              }
              args.Dispose();
          }
          else
              throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.NotConnected);
        }

        public void Connect()
        {

          logger.Trace("Connect()");
          SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

          args.UserToken = socket;
          args.RemoteEndPoint = endPoint;
          args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnConnect);

          socket.ConnectAsync(args);
          autoEvent.WaitOne();

          if (args.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
              throw new SocketException((int)args.SocketError);
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
          logger.Trace("Disconnect()");
          socket.Close();
        }

        #region Events

        private void OnConnect(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
          logger.Trace("OnConnect");
          autoEvent.Set();
          isConnected = (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success);
        }

        private void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
          //logger.Trace("OnReceive {0} bytes", e.BytesTransferred);
          if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
          {
            autoReceiveEvent.Set();
          }
        }

        private void OnSend(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
          //logger.Trace("OnSend Bytes={0}", e.BytesTransferred);

          autoSendEvent.Set();

          if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
          {
              if (e.LastOperation == SocketAsyncOperation.Send)
              {
              }
          }
          else
          {
              ProcessError(e);
          }
        }

        #endregion

        private void ProcessError(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
          logger.Trace("ProcessError");
          Socket s = e.UserToken as Socket;
          if (s.Connected)
          {
              try
              {
                  s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
              }
              catch (Exception)
              {
              }
              finally
              {
                  if (s.Connected)
                      s.Close();
              }
          }

          throw new SocketException((int)e.SocketError);
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
          logger.Trace("Dispose");
          autoEvent.Close();
          autoSendEvent.Close();
          autoReceiveEvent.Close();
          if (socket.Connected)
              socket.Close();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```